# DataTable importrow skipping some values

Tags: c#

We have a function which does the following

- Given a DataRow
- Creates a clone of the dataset
- Imports the given row in the clone

So far, we never had any issue with this. But, there is a condition which has occured where in, the row which is created after import is skipping/nulling out some values.

I have really no clue as to why this is happening

```
private DataSet GetFullDataSetForCurrentRow(DataRow currentRow)
{
    DataSet clone = null;
    if (currentRow != null)
    {
        clone = currentRow.Table.DataSet.Clone();
        // Get the parent row.
        DataRow rootRow = GetRootRow(currentRow);
        // Import the root row in the clone.
        clone.Tables[rootRow.Table.TableName].ImportRow(rootRow);
        // additonal code skipped...
    }
    return clone;
}
```

So, the rootRow has the correct values, but if i inspect the imported row, its loosing/skipping some values.

Check the screenshots.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiPRD.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJR9Z.png

Comment: What does GetRootRow-method do?

Comment: There are multiple child relations, it just fetches the header/root row (if the currentRow which is passed in is not the header/root row). So in this case it just returns back the currentRow

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
The value that was being set in the column was larger than the size of the column.
An exception was generated but swallowed.

Thus, while importing the row, it skipped those values.

I am really not sure, how the values were stored in the first place though. Because there was an exception, it should have ideally not stored the value.